# Have the lyrics of the Song of Father Dûchene (Chanson du Père Dûchene) been translated into English?

Tags: french-language, song-lyrics

The Song of Father Dûchene (Chanson du Père Dûchene) is an anarchist song written anonymously in France, probably in 1892, and which was famously sung by [Ravachol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravachol) on his way to the guillotine in July of that year. Père Dûchene was a fictional figure and the title of [an extremist revolutionary newspaper published by Jacques Hébert in 1790-94](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_P%C3%A8re_Duchesne).

Several recordings of the song have been made in French, including by the [Quatres Barbus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFejYiLOWyU),
[René Binamé](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_qkjpVYTbE), and in 1968 by [Jacques Marchais](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlS5xmL-L6I) under the title "L'bon Dieu dans la merde".

Have the lyrics ever been translated into English?

<sub>Note: I clarify having read @PeterShor's comment that I am interested in whether the lyrics (words to a song) in French have ever been translated into lyrics (words to a song, whatever the tune) in English.</sub>

Comment: Do you want a translation of the lyrics, do you want English lyrics that can be sung to the original tune, or or do you want a musical rendition in English? These are three different things.

Comment: Listening to the four or five renditions song available on YouTube, it appears that there is essentially only one tune, so any translation of the lyrics should ideally be set to that tune.

Comment: Of course it's always sung to the same tune in French. Let's see whether anyone knows of a translation of the lyrics into English whether set to that tune or any other tune. That's what this question asks.